# Having Trouble Implementing Column Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, case

I'm attempting to find the lifespan of purchased tools based on their first transaction and their status on an Oracle DB. I used a CASE function to create a new column that returns 'active tool' for one that doesn't have this status, and returns the scrap date if there is one. I then want to, based on that column calculate the age of the tool. If it is still 'active...' then it would be today's date minus it's first status date. If it is scrapped it should subtract the scrapped date from the first status date.

I can get the column rendered, but I'm not understanding how to create the column (multi row?) subquery so that I can reference it. The code below was my naive assumption, which I understand will not work.

```
SELECT SERIALTOOL.SERIALID,
       SERIALTOOL.ITEMNUMBER,
       MIN (SERIALTOOL.STATUSDATE) AS "Purchase Date",
       CASE
          WHEN SERIALTOOL.STATUS = 5 THEN TO_CHAR (SERIALTOOL.STATUSDATE)
          ELSE 'Active Tool'
       END AS "Scrap Date",
       CASE
          WHEN "Scrap Date" = 'Active Tool'
          THEN CURRENT_DATE - MIN (SERIALTOOL.STATUSDATE)
          ELSE "Scrap Date" - MIN (SERIALTOOL.STATUSDATE)
       END AS "TOOL AGE"
FROM SERVER.SERIALTOOL SERIALTOOL
```

Comment: `min` is an aggregate function, so you have to specify `group by` with expressions that should form a group. Another way is to use analytic `min` adding `over(partition by <grouping expressions to calculate min>)`

Comment: Thanks, I know I need the group by's, i cut them out of the sample, I'll keep the stuff in next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually quite close. In order to mix aggregates and un-aggregated columns, you have to use windowing ( `OVER` clause ), and since you are using CASE logic on derived columns you need to nest your query blocks, like this:

```
SELECT SERIALID,
       ITEMNUMBER,
       "Purchase Date",
       STATUS,
       STATUSDATE,
       CASE
          WHEN STATUS = 5 THEN TO_CHAR (STATUSDATE)
          ELSE 'Active Tool'
       END AS "Scrap Date",
       CASE
          WHEN STATUS != 5 THEN SYSDATE - "Purchase Date"
          ELSE STATUSDATE - "Purchase Date"
       END AS "TOOL AGE"
  FROM (SELECT SERIALID,
               ITEMNUMBER,
               MIN (STATUSDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY serialid) AS "Purchase Date",
               STATUS,
               STATUSDATE
          FROM SERVER.SERIALTOOL)
```

Oh, and you should probably stick with Oracle-legal column names so you don't require "" and case sensitivity. All uppercase, no special chars except _ and #, and starting with an alpha character.

Comment: I'm attempting to work off of this, however, I'm confused about the two FROM statements... One is for the subquery and the other is for the main query, correct?

Comment: This is what I call nested query blocks. Each query block has its own SELECT, FROM and optionally also WHERE/GROUP BY, etc.. clauses. The results of each query block, surrounded by parenthesis, are passed into the outer (parent) query block as if they were the rows from a real table. This way you can break up a complex task into multiple discrete steps, as if you were working with temp tables and going from one stage of transformation to the other, only this takes place in memory. So think of the inner queyr block as the first SQL, and its results are then the "table" for the outer SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this last post fixed my brain, and I was able to conceptualize the whole issue. Couple that with @rgm575 reminding me that there is DATEINSERVICE field that allowed me to get rid of that grouping stuff. I've got it!

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that:

- `serialtool.serialid` identifies the tool
- `serialtool.itemnumber` lists transactions per tool
- `serialtool.itemnumber = 1` indicates the purchase transaction
- `serialtool.status = 5` indicates the tool has been scrapped
- tools can be scrapped only once

I would suggest something like this:

```
WITH scrapped_tools AS (
    SELECT st.serialid,
           st.itemnumber,
           st.statusdate AS scrapped_date
    FROM   serialtool st
    WHERE  st.status = 5)
SELECT st.serialid,
       st.itemnumber AS purchase_entry,
       st.statusdate AS purchase_date,
       NVL2 (scr.serialid, 'Active', 'Scrapped') AS tool_status,
       NVL2 (scr.serialid,
           SYSDATE - st.statusdate,
           scr.statusdate - st.statusdate) AS tool_age
FROM   serialtool st
           LEFT OUTER JOIN scrapped_tools scr ON st.serialid = scr.serialid
WHERE  st.itemnumber = 1;
```

Further to the earlier answer, my preference is for keywords and Oracle-supplied functions to be in upper case; user-defined names are in lower case.

For versions pre-`NVL2()`, use `DECODE (scr.serialid, NULL, 'Active', 'Scrapped')`

Comment: Sorry, I'm also learning how to make these questions as  well as write the code.
serialid is a unique item
itemnumber is the type of tool
(min) statusdate is the "purchase date" (although, i think there might be an actual discrete value)
status = 5 indicates the tool has been scrapped

Just wanted to clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rgm575 I realized that there was a "DATEINSERVICE" field that I could use and could avoid using the oldest status date. Thanks to @paul-w for spoon feeding me subquery info. Additionally to keep it simple, I kept the dates even for items still in service and added an additional column for the tool's status.

```
 SELECT a.SERIALID,
         a.ITEMNUMBER,
         a.DATEINSERVICE,
         CASE
            WHEN a.SCRAP_DATE = CURRENT_DATE
            THEN
               ROUND (CURRENT_DATE - a.DATEINSERVICE)
            ELSE
               ROUND (a.SCRAP_DATE - a.DATEINSERVICE)
         END AS TOOL_AGE,
         a.TOOL_STATUS
  FROM (SELECT SERIALTOOL.SERIALID,
               SERIALTOOL.ITEMNUMBER,
               SERIALTOOL.DATEINSERVICE,
               CASE
                  WHEN SERIALTOOL.STATUS = 5 THEN SERIALTOOL.STATUSDATE
                  ELSE CURRENT_DATE
               END AS SCRAP_DATE,
               CASE
                  WHEN SERIALTOOL.STATUS = 5 THEN 'Scrapped'
                  ELSE 'In Service'
               END AS TOOL_STATUS
        FROM SERVER.SERIALTOOL SERIALTOOL
        WHERE (    SERIALTOOL.HOMECRIB = 823
               AND SERIALTOOL.DATEINSERVICE > CURRENT_DATE - 5475)) a
```